# g-bd-part-error-quark error during format of sd-card

Tags: gparted, sd-card

Recently my sd card stopped working in a photocamera. When I insert it into sd card reader OS can't recognize it (at least this disk is not showed up in the sidebar menu). But at the same time it's accessible through the Disks tool. It has correctly determined size of the sd card (16GB) and lists one Unknown volume on it. When I try to format the disk I'm getting next error:

```
Error formatting disk
Failed to commit changes to device '/dev/sdc' (Input/output error during write on /dev/sdc) (g-bd-part-error-quark, 2)
```

Unfortunately I have found only one topic with similar [error](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2457090) and according to it might be unrecoverable error.

Additionally I have tried to create partition table using gparted, but I had to kill it after 5 minutes, because it has stopped responding.

Is there any workaround that I can try to fix it?

Comment: Sounds like the card has gone bad. That is something that can not be fixed.

Comment: Please follow the syslog contents while you are trying to do IO on your SD card. Your will probably see many IO errors on that device. Also look at the S.M.A.R.T. info of the device.

Comment: It's dead, in a nutshell. Replace it.

Comment: FedKad, do you have a link on how to check syslog content? And what is a S.M.A.R.T. info?